# Android Material Toolbar Overlapping with Status Bar when trying Edge to Edge design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-navigation-bar

I was trying to implement edge to edge design to take full advantage of the screen in Android Q but i am having some issues with it.

My code is as follows:

activity:

```
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/Drawer_Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout_Coordinator_Main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutFullscreen="@{true}">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorOnSurface"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorShadowColor"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorShadowColor"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

...
```

BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("layoutFullscreen")
fun View.bindLayoutFullscreen(previousFullscreen: Boolean, fullscreen: Boolean) {
    if (previousFullscreen != fullscreen && fullscreen) {
        systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    }
}
```

v29\colors.xml (For Android Q Only)

```
<resources>
    <!--Set the navigation bar to transparent on Q+ and allow the system to guard against-->
    <!--low contrast scenarios.-->
    <color name="nav_bar">@android:color/transparent</color>
</resources>
```

colors.xml:

```
<!--Set the navigation bar to transparent on Q+ and allow the system to guard against-->
<!--low contrast scenarios.-->
<color name="nav_bar">@color/colorPrimaryDark</color>
```

themes.xml

```
    <!-- Status and navigation bar colors -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">@bool/theme_status_bar_light</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/nav_bar</item>
```

The navigation works well, however, my toolbar is overlapping with the status bar as such:

[image: Status bar issue]

I've already tried the following:

```
- <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
- android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

It still doesn't work.

EDIT

I've also tried @Gabriele Mariotti's answer

I added the code below in my onCreate():

```
val paddingTop = _binding.ToolbarMain.paddingTop
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(_binding.ToolbarMain){v, insets ->
        v.updatePadding(top = paddingTop + insets.systemWindowInsetTop)
        insets
    }
```

The end result is this:

[image: issue 2]

I am still losing part of my material toolbar.

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to handle the `WindowInsets` in your `AppBarLayout` (or `Toolbar` if you don't use it).

Something like:

```
   val appbar : AppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar)
   val appbarTopPadding = appbar.paddingTop

   ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(appbar) { v, insets ->
         v.updatePadding(top = appbarTopPadding + insets.systemWindowInsets.top)
         insets
   }
```

With:

[image]

Without:

[image]

You can find more [info here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-handling-visual-overlaps-4aed565c134c).

Comment: Hi, i have updated my code above. Can you please help me ? I don't know why i am still losing part of my toolbar

Answer (score 0):

themes.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

Comment: Please add a little bit of context around your answer. Why is this the solution?